# Unable to run a lifecycle command from config.yaml while deploying jupyterhub

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, kubernetes-helm

I want to run a command as soon as a pod is created and starts running. I am deploying `jupyterhub` but the config that I am using is:

```
proxy:
  secretToken: "yada yada"
singleuser:
  image:
    # Get the latest image tag at:
    # https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/datascience-notebook/tags/
    # Inspect the Dockerfile at:
    # https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/datascience-notebook/Dockerfile
    name: jupyter/datascience-notebook
    # name: ${IMAGE}
    tag: 177037d09156
    # tag: latest
  lifecycle:
    postStart:
      exec:
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello from the postStart handler > /usr/share/message"]
```

When the pod is up and running, I am not able to see the file `/usr/share/message` and hence, I deduce that the exec command is not running.

What is the right way to make this command work?

Comment: Hi, can you run `kubectl describe pod $POD_NAME` ?

Comment: @SureshVishnoi https://pastebin.com/dpUVdFJV

Comment: Are there any events ? there is not event sections, usually it describe the sequence of events

Comment: If you want to take a look at helm: https://jupyterhub.github.io/helm-chart/

Comment: @SureshVishnoi
Yes there are, I deleted it from the file, apologies. The events are: https://pastebin.com/a4CMEMMN

Comment: command:
              - /bin/sh 
              - -c
              - echo "Hello from the postStart handler" > /usr/share/message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193477/discussion-between-suresh-vishnoi-and-aviral-srivastava).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct key for **lifecycle** stanza is **lifecyleHooks**.

Following blob is with the correct values.

```
proxy:
  secretToken: "yada yada"
singleuser:
  image:
    # Get the latest image tag at:
    # https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/datascience-notebook/tags/
    # Inspect the Dockerfile at:
    # https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/datascience-notebook/Dockerfile
    name: jupyter/datascience-notebook
    # name: ${IMAGE}
    tag: 177037d09156
    # tag: latest
  lifecycleHooks:
    postStart:
      exec:
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello from the postStart handler > /usr/share/message"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write it out as shown below with "lifecycleHooks".

Note, this could also be used for multiple commands by adding extra commands delimited by ";"

You can add extra commands after the "echo" command.

```
proxy:
  secretToken: "yada yada"
singleuser:
  image:
    # Get the latest image tag at:
    # https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/datascience-notebook/tags/
    # Inspect the Dockerfile at:
    # https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/datascience-notebook/Dockerfile
    name: jupyter/datascience-notebook
    # name: ${IMAGE}
    tag: 177037d09156
    # tag: latest
  lifecycleHooks:
    postStart:
      exec:
        command:
          - /bin/sh
          - -c
          - |
            echo "Hello from the postStart handler" > /usr/share/message;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).